# (PHP) struggling with the variable inside a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

To give some context, this is the code that the for loop refers to: putting the form data into an array.

```
         $_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$count] = array (

        'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID'),
        'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_name'),
        'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_price'),
        'list_price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_list_price'),
        'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')

       );

    $count = count($_SESSION['shoppingcart']);

    $product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shoppingcart'], 'id');
```

This is all well and good: I understand what this code does. It's just the 'for' loop and everything that involves the variable '$i' outside of the for loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($product_ids); $i++) { 

if ($product_ids[$i] == filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID')) {

$_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$i]['quantity'] += 
filter_input(INPUT_POST,'quantity');

            }
        }
```

So, the `$i` variable. What does it represent in the for loop and why is it/ what does it represent in square brackets in the 'if' statement.

I should say that this code accomplishes its  intended purpose (putting form data into an array, incrementing the `quantity` if the item in the array already exists.)
I got the code from a YouTube tutorial, only he didn't explain the `$i` part.

Comment: Did you even look in the manual before posting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the manual has good documentation of how a for loop works

Comment: Please don’t download code from the web and use it when you don’t understand it. Doing so will just leave your application full of bugs and security vulnerabilities, and, when your server gets hijacked, will make the internet more dangerous for everyone.

Comment: Also, a `for` loop is one of the most basic programming concepts in the vast majority of languages, certainly all languages that are “C-like.” If you don’t know how a `for` loop works, my best advice to you is to take the time to go through some basic tutorials before doing anything else. Trying to learn to program without understanding loops will just cause you a great deal of frustration.

Comment: Agreed with @EdCottrell about security. For example `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID')` looks it might filter something, but the default filter is FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everytime you complete an iteration of your loop the `$i` variable will increase by `$i++` (thus in this case by 1) until this condition: `$i < count($product_ids)` is met. This is particularly useful for accessing elements in an array sequentially, namely `if ($product_ids[$i] == filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID'))` is used to access each element of `$product_ids` and check if that value is equal to `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID')`.

its also worth to note that `$i = 0` is the initialization of $i. This only happens once when you first enter the for loop.